# Access a UILabel from code during runtime from a string

Tags: ios, swift

I have 5 labels in my storyboard with 5 numbers (1-5). I have a random number generator. Now, the number that is generated should have the background turned to gray and text to white.
my labels are defined below:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var num1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var num2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var num3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var num4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var num5: UILabel!
```

now for example the random number generator gives number 1, i want to select label 1.
so i can make the required string as such:

```
let labelName = "num" + Str(randomlyGeneratedNumber)
```

But as you can see it is a string and i am not able to make it a UILabel to access the text and other properties.

I checked the documentation and various posts in StackOverflow, but all the solutions are about to do stuff with the UILabel but not how to access a UILabel like the way i want to.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can define a dictionary `let nums = ["num1": num1, … "num5": num5]`, and access your labels using `let label = nums[labelName]`.

Comment: Thank you Reinhard, your solution worked, but it would be tedious to write to as many key value pairs as there are labels.

Comment: If you have so many labels, maybe it would be easier (I don't know your user interface) to use a tableView instead?

Answer (score 0):

Variable names are evaluated at compile time, you cannot compose dynamic variable names at runtime

Declare the labels as outlet collection

```
@IBOutlet var labels: [UILabel]!
```

and connect the labels in Interface Builder in the desired order

Now you can get the label by index, consider that indices in Swift are zero-based.

```
let label = labels[randomlyGeneratedNumber - 1]
```

Comment: Hi, i am new so my responses may be likewise, but i have 2 questions:
1. Can i mention all the 5 labels like u just mentioned ?
2. in your first line, you have said that we cannot compose dynamic variable names. but i do not want to compose a new one. Just want a way to access the already created label.

Comment: 1) The 5 labels are represented by the `UILabel` array. It's a shortcut for `let labels = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5]` 2) `"num" + Str(randomlyGeneratedNumber)` is composing a variable name. You cannot do this.

Comment: Thank you...exactly what i needed.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set tag to the UILabel.

```
num1.tag = 1
num2.tag = 2
num3.tag = 3
num4.tag = 4
num5.tag = 5
```

Also you can set the tag in .xib file while creating label.

Then you can fetch the label based on the random number generated.

```
let label = self.view.viewWithTag(randomlyGeneratedNumber) as! UILabel
```

Comment: i will have to check how it would work, but again if there are more than a handful labels, it would be tedious tagging them. The above solution Vadian seems very apt.